# Why Change IE11 Language does not have effectiveness on date format in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, windows-10, internet-explorer-11, date-format, currentculture

Just a simple question, i notice that in my mvc application the current culture thread does not follow the language set in browser setting.

I use IE11 and on windows 10 (the last released build).

Whatewer the date format was set to English (US) d/MM/yyyy my mvc asp net application always show data in european format, because the thread culture is set to IT.

It's strange because i didn't encounter this behaviour on previous windows versione like windows 7.

It could be related to geolocalization enabled in the windows setting? or any cortana setting?? I thought about windows 10 is now 'smart' and depending on location where we connect it will set automatically the language on thread, ignoring the browser language setting...

NB: my pc is registered under domain of my company.
Sometimes disabling localization i see the date agree with the langauge set in browser, but i can't understand exacty how it work or if it fully related on this setting.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Regards.

Comment: You mean you go to a website and the website shows dates in different format? If the website isn't configured to care about your browser's settings, it will output whatever it wants. Or is the site using JavaScript to show the date?

Comment: Is you application configured to use automated UI settings as described here: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Mar/27/Auto-Selecting-Cultures-for-Localization-in-ASPNET

Perhaps just the setting got lost along the way. Another thing to check for is what culture the browser actually requests in the HTTP headers (you can use Fiddler to inspect the HTTP requests the browser sends).